# Retrieve Alias From Display Name In Excel

Tags: excel, outlook, active-directory

Is there a way to return a users alias/userid from their display name in excel?

Example:
In excel, cell A2 would = John Doe
Cell B2 would look up John Doe's alias or username from Outlook and return 'jdoe' for example

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Alias` (null and error checking omitted) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser